# yammer embed config options

Tags: embed, yammer

I have been searching and I couldn't find it in Yammer's documentation, can anyone give me a list of the config options for the Yammer embed? Or a link to where I can find a full list and not just the five that they choose to give in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The options documented are the only configuration options that exist for Yammer Embed. If you need more control, it might be better to use the REST APIs.